# automapper example for ado.net to viewmodel mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, ado.net, automapper

i have not used automapper before, is there a link with a sample of how to map dataset rows to a asp.net mvc 2 viewmodel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoMapper doesn't excel in mapping between non strongly typed dataset rows and view models. Here's what I would suggest you: use an ORM to map between your SQL tables and a model and then AutoMapper to map between the model and the view model. Another advantage is that you would get rid of the datasets as well.